# Who was responsible for Prince Joffrey's education?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I think most of us will agree that Joffrey is the most annoying character in GoT. But it's not clear *why*.

Who was responsible formally for his education? The TV show seems to state that it was his mother, but I can't find a book reference that backs this up.

The question is; Are there any official tutors or mentors for the young Prince Joffrey? AFAIK from history, kings were generally too busy to raise their own children so there are usually specially hired teachers. **Is there anyone officially a teacher or tutor of Joffrey in the GoT books?**

Comment: The most annoying character in GoT is Janos Slynt. This has been peer-reviewed.

Comment: He just seems like a spoiled brat to me. Nothing to do with education. I've known a few people that had good education but were disliked and spoiled

Comment: I wouldn't say Joffrey is the most annoying character. He is the most _hateful_ character, in a spoiled-brat-that-can-kill-you sort of way.

Comment: Still can't surpass Sansa imho...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

'Responsible for' and 'most influence on' are two different things. The Maester may have been formally responsible for Joffrey's education, but the relationship between mother and son in this case was far stronger. I can't find anything in the GoT book, but from the TV show witness the moment when Cersei essentially tells him to ignore everything but his own desires (from s1 ep3):

> Someday, you'll sit on the throne and the truth will be what you make it.

And a minute later:

> You are my darling boy and the world will be exactly as you want it to be.

If that's not putting him on the road to be an arrogant little bastard, nothing is. And of course, as king-in-waiting and member of the richest family in Westeros, he's spoiled beyond belief. The saddest part is that in this very scene he's showing regret and maybe a little fear and humility about the whole incident with the Stark girls, but Cersei beats that out of him and makes him believe it was all *their* fault instead. Mothering perfection. And the cherry on the cake:

> Everyone who isn't us is an enemy.

So to answer your question; yes, his mother was his 'official' tutor. And the Seven help anyone who tried to argue that with her.

Comment: +1 I get the impression that whatever was wrong in Joffrey's upbringing, it was Cersei's fault (it can be argued that Jaime is also to blame, for being an absent father). Both Cersei and Joffrey are hateful, cruel characters; it's just that Joffrey is also a kid, prone to childish whims. Whims that can kill people, regrettably.

Comment: I'd imagine a fair bit is due to him having Robert as his (not knowingly) adoptive father, who didn't care for Joffrey at all

Comment: To add: Cersei and Kevan Lannister speak after a certain funeral " ...“The king is my son!” Cersei rose to her feet.
“Aye,” her uncle said, “and from what I saw of Joffrey, you are as unfit a mother as you are a ruler.”... " Looks like Cersei has a **lot** of influence in the up-bringing of her children.

Comment: I agree he probably had a unofficial teacher but his mother was probably always whispering in his ear like when he had a king's hand, he had one and he also had his mother who was always talking to him and advising him.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the responsibility for educating highborn children falls to the Maester in residence. In the case of Joffrey, that'd be Grand Maester Pycelle, who, as we have seen, is... Not the finest representative of his order.

Comment: A reference for this answer could improve it a lot.